# ViewWillDisappear() not working as intented

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to implement something similar to `OnBackPressed` from **Android** and this is what I've got so far:

```
public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
    if(isTrue)
    {
        // Go to previous controller
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated)
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Stay on the current controller
    }
}
```

However, this does not seem to work as `base.ViewWillDisappear()` is always called. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always make a custom back button.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let customBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.backClicked(sender:)))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackButton
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
  }


  func backClicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if(isTrue){
      // Go to previous controller
      _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    else{
      // Stay on the current controller
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The strict answer is that you can't. Swipe right gesture will always go back, no matter what.

Other than that if you are fine just with disabling this on the back button press, you can use the custom button trick in David's answer.